# LG G3 Wifi Connection Issues

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, connection-issues, lg-g3

This started like a week ago, my phone wont connect to my WiFi properly.

Issues:

- Unable to locate my WiFi (it cant search/ find my WiFi)
- 'Authentication Problem' shows when it is connecting to the WiFi (there is another one I can't remember)
- States that 'Internet is unavailable' occasionally when it connects
- It will connect to WiFi for like 5 secs before dropping again

In the beginning I thought my phone had lost its WiFi range as I would just walk into my office (where my router is) and it would connect, now that is not the case, it is a mixture of the above issues usually simultaneously occurring. It isn't a router issue as my other devices work flawlessly.

*My router emits 2 bands of WiFi (2.4 and 5 GHz) and I've tried using both.

I've tried:

- Restarting both phone and router
- Toggling airplane mode, WiFi and Battery Saver
- Deleting apps prior to the problem

This seems like a common issue within the android community, and I've searched relentlessly for a fix (permanent rather than temporal). If possible I would prefer to not have to factory reset my phone.

Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: At this point, I guess a [tag:factory-reset] won't help you, as it seems to be a system configuration issue. A stock ROM flash would probably help, however.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact issue. Literally same exact issue. I got mine to work for a little while after setting my WiFi to broadcast B&G only. I really hope someone finds out how to fix this issue soon. Btw I'm running XDAbbeb's ROM and have tried 3 or 4 others.

Edit: People on the G3 reddit are reporting this issue as well. One user said that replacing the battery fixes the issue.

Comment: Its sad that this such is a common issue. The battery 'fix' is interesting as I had replaced my battery ~2 months ago, I'll try reverting back to my old battery and see what happens.

Comment: Oh btw, reverting back to my old battery allowed me to be able to use my WiFi again (although I literally must be standing next to it). I've done some research and I think that the problem might be due to hardware failure (short circuiting).